# PrimeFaces button navigation action

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with navigating the pages through buttons.

My current xhtml snippet is like that:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" header="Menü" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton type="button" value="New Project" icon="ui-icon-document" action="#{createProject.create()}"/>


                <p:commandButton type="button" value="All Projects" icon="ui-icon-folder-open"/>

                <p:commandButton type="button" value="Edit" icon="ui-icon-pencil"/>

                <p:commandButton type="button" value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-closethick"/>

                <p:separator />
                <p:commandButton type="button" title="Yazdır" icon="ui-icon-print"></p:commandButton>
            </p:column>

        </p:layoutUnit>
```

Here, when I click on New Project it doesn't navigate to related page.

My beanfile:

```
  @ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class CreateProject {
    /**
     * Creates a new instance of CreateProject
     */
    public String create() {
        return "newproject.xhtml";
    }
}
```

How can I navigate user when the button is clicked?

edit: here is my faces-config

```
    <faces-config
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>loginBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.ibb.source.LoginBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>myProjects</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.ibb.source.MyProjects</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>myCalendar</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.ibb.source.MyCalendar</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/panel.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>create</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>newproject.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
  </navigation-rule>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>createProject</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.ibb.source.CreateProject</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
      </managed-bean>
        <managed-bean>
            <managed-bean-name>inPlaceEditor</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.ibb.source.InPlaceEditor</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
        </managed-bean>
        <managed-bean>
            <managed-bean-name>projectsList</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.ibb.source.ProjectsList</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
        </managed-bean>
        <navigation-rule>
           <from-view-id>panel.xhtml</from-view-id>
           <navigation-case>
               <from-outcome>newproject</from-outcome>
               <to-view-id>/newproject.xhtml</to-view-id>
           </navigation-case>
        </navigation-rule>
        <managed-bean>
            <managed-bean-name>allProjects</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.ibb.source.AllProjects</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
        </managed-bean>
        <managed-bean>
            <managed-bean-name>allProjectsList</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.ibb.source.AllProjectsList</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
        </managed-bean>
    </faces-config>
```

Comment: have you tried using navigation-rule in faces-config

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code:

```
type="button"
```

makes commandbutton a simple javascript trigger.
If you want to do anything on the server, you must remove type="button".
Also, your method defined on action tag, must return a string corresponding to your desired view, and you don`t need yo use an xml for defining navigation.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

By default, `commandButton` component of the PrimeFaces, uses ajax to send the commands so navigations won't work. Set the `ajax` property to `false`:

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" value="New Project" icon="ui-icon-document" action="#{createProject.create()}" />
```

Also make sure that your buttons are inside a form element. Put a `<h:form> ... </h:form>` around your whole `<p:layoutUnit>` tag.

Comment: @Ali What do you mean of 'doesn't work'? Do the page reloads but remains in the same page? Or nothing happens? Or you get and error?

Comment: @Ali Did you try using standard commandButton (`<h:commandButton>`)?

Comment: I have also tried with <h:commandButton>. and it stays like that. The page neither reloads, nor remains. It's like you click the button with no code under to trigger it.  I have also tried with navigation rule in faces-config

Comment: @Ali This is a little strange and I don't understand your statement. When you click a button (with ajax set to false), one these should happen: a. Your page should reload to the same URL; b. Your page should load to a new URL; c. You should get an error; d. Absolutely nothing happens! (the last is the case when ajax is enabled).

Answer (score 2):

Add into faces-config.xml

```
<navigation-rule>
       <from-view-id>page1.xhtml</from-view-id>
       <navigation-case>
           <from-outcome>page2</from-outcome>
           <to-view-id>/newproject.xhtml</to-view-id>
       </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>



@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class CreateProject {
    /**
     * Creates a new instance of CreateProject
     */
    public String create() {
        return "page2";
    }
}

 <p:commandButton type="button" value="New Project" icon="ui-icon-document" action="#{createProject.create}"/>
```

Comment: check your create method is called or not? use some printing into create().

Comment: @Ali, have you found your solution?

Comment: create() method is calling or not?

Comment: Well it is calling. But I could not figure out how to get it work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by using `button` instead of `commandButton`. Note that `outcome` is used instead of `action`.

```
 <p:button ajax="false" value="New Project" icon="ui-icon-document" outcome="#{createProject.create}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To perform an action when pressing a `commandButton`, you need to change:

```
<p:commandButton type="button" value="New Project" icon="ui-icon-document" action="#{createProject.create()}"/>
```

to:

```
<p:commandButton type="button" value="New Project" icon="ui-icon-document" action="#{createProject.create}"/>
```

without the "`()`"

The String returned by the method can either be a page (like your example) or a navigation rule (faces-navigation)

Comment: is the page you're trying to return, in the same folder as this page?

Comment: remove the [type="button"] part and try again. CommandButton already indicates type="button".

<p:commandButton value="New Project" icon="ui-icon-document" action="#{createProject.create}"/>

Comment: when I remove it, it does nothing. it gives: CommandButton : "j_idt17" must be inside a form element

Comment: `p:commandButton` should always be inside a form.
Enclose your buttons inside `h:form` tags, and this should work

Comment: it may be because of nested form ? @AliYucelAkgul